Autocomplete via infer not working as expected
I want to incrementally build a functionality that works as follows:
import commands from "./commands"

const command = commands.builder().withOption("option1").withOption("option2").build();
const parsed = command.parse(); /* should return { option1: <unknown>, option2: <unknown> } */

where typescript should automatically infer that parsed has a type of { option1: unknown, option2: unknown }
Therefore I created a module with the follows as the source:
type ParsedOptions<A extends string[]> = { [K in A[number]]: unknown };

interface Command<A extends string[]> {
    parse: () => ParsedOptions<A>;
}

interface CommandBuilder<A extends string[]> {
    withOption: <K extends string>(option: K) => CommandBuilder<[...A, K]>;
    build: () => Command<A>;
}

const builder = <A extends string[]>(...options: A): CommandBuilder<A> => {
    return {
        withOption: option => builder(...options, option),
        build: () => ({ parse: () => ({} as any) }),
    };
};

export default { builder };

The above snippet infers the parsed result's type correctly which is ParsedOptions<["option1", "option2"]>
Now I want to further extend the functionality so that I can send either string or {name: string} in withOption function, while maintaining the autocomplete functionality provided by typescript inference. But after making changes the autocomplete functionality breaks.
I initially changed the code to something as follows:
interface OptionDefinition<K extends string> {
    name: K;
}

type OptionSource<K extends string> = K | OptionDefinition<K>;

type ParsedOptions<A extends string[]> = { [K in A[number]]: unknown };

interface Command<A extends string[]> {
    parse: () => ParsedOptions<A>;
}

interface CommandBuilder<A extends string[]> {
    withOption: <K extends string>(option: OptionSource<K>) => CommandBuilder<[...A, K]>;
    build: () => Command<A>;
}

const deriveOption = <K extends string>(option: OptionSource<K>): OptionDefinition<K> => {
    return typeof option === "object" ? option : { name: option };
};

const builder = <A extends string[]>(...options: OptionDefinition<A[number]>[]): CommandBuilder<A> => {
    return {
        withOption: option => builder(...options, deriveOption(option)),
        build: () => ({ parse: () => ({} as any) }),
    };
};

export default { builder };

But now the type returned by command.parse() is ParsedOptions<[...string[], "option1", "option2"]> rather than the expected ParsedOptions<["option1", "option2"]>. And because the actual return type contains ...string[], typescript loses the autocomplete functionality by inference.
Is there a way to retain the autocomplete even after changing the input for withOption from string to OptionSource?
Playground

OS: Windows 11
Node.js version: 20.17.0
TypeScript version: ^5.5.4


Your problem is that one cannot infer A from options of type OptionDefinition<A[number]>[] (since A[number] is just a union of things). If you want to say that each element of options is of the corresponding OptionDefinition type of A, then you need a mapped type as shown in this playground link. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

@jcalz that does clarify my question, I further analyzed your playground code and found that the implementation also satisfies my future needs, thanks a lot

The problem with
<A extends string[]>(...options: OptionDefinition<A[number]>[]) => ⋯

is that OptionDefinition<A[number]>[] completely throws away any order and length information present in the A type parameter. If someone calls builder() with no argument, you want A to be the empty tuple type [], so that you get CommandBuilder<[]> instead of, say, CommandBuilder<never[]>. And there's no hope of even inferring A from the indexed access type A[number] anyway, since TypeScript does not infer type parameters from indexes into them There's a pull request at microsoft/TypeScript#53017 which, if merged, might enable this, but it's not part of the language.

If you want A to be the tuple of string literal types such that options is the tuple of corresponding OptionDefinition types, then what you're really trying to do is make a mapped tuple type, like
<A extends string[]>(...options: { [I in keyof A]: OptionDefinition<A[I]> }) => ⋯

Now when you call builder(), TypeScript will look at each argument in turn, and use it to infer the corresponding element of the A tuple. When you call builder() with no arguments, A will therefore be [] and you'll get your desired behavior:
const command = builder().withOption("option1").withOption("option2").build();
// const command: Command<["option1", "option2"]>


That answers the question as asked. Still, I'd say you're only making things unnecessarily difficult for yourself by forcing TypeScript to keep track of the exact order and number of string literal types in A but then when you actually use that information you just throw away the order and length and just use A[number]. You might as well just use a string type and then join them in a union to start with:
type ParsedOptions<A extends string> = { [K in A]: undefined };

interface Command<A extends string> {
    parse: () => ParsedOptions<A>;
}

interface OptionDefinition<K extends string> {
    name: K;
}

type OptionSource<K extends string> = K | OptionDefinition<K>;

interface CommandBuilder<A extends string> {
    withOption: <K extends string>(option: OptionSource<K>) => CommandBuilder<A | K>;
    build: () => Command<A>;
}

const deriveOption = <K extends string>(option: OptionSource<K>): OptionDefinition<K> => {
    return typeof option === "object" ? option : { name: option };
};

const builder = <A extends string = never>(
   ...options: OptionDefinition<A>[]): CommandBuilder<A> => {
    return {
        withOption: option => builder(...options, deriveOption(option as OptionSource<string>)),
        build: () => ({ parse: () => ({} as any) }),
    };
};

const command = builder().withOption("option1").withOption("option2").build();
// const command: Command<"option1" | "option2">

This gives you the same behavior without worrying about order. I won't go deeply into how this works because it's technically not what you're asking about.
Playground link to code
